# Spark Structured Streaming watermark error

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

Followup to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53090467/convert-an-spark-dataframe-columns-with-an-array-of-json-objects-to-multiple-row)

I have json streaming data in the format same as below

```
|  A    | B                                        |
|-------|------------------------------------------|
|  ABC  |  [{C:1, D:1}, {C:2, D:4}]                | 
|  XYZ  |  [{C:3, D :6}, {C:9, D:11}, {C:5, D:12}] |
```

I need to transform it to the format below

```
|   A   |  C  |  D   |
|-------|-----|------|
|  ABC  |  1  |  1   |
|  ABC  |  2  |  4   |
|  XYZ  |  3  |  6   |
|  XYZ  |  9  |  11  |
|  XYZ  |  5  |  12  |
```

To achieve this performed the transformations as suggested to the previous question.

```
val df1 = df0.select($"A", explode($"B")).toDF("A", "Bn")

val df2 = df1.withColumn("SeqNum", monotonically_increasing_id()).toDF("A", "Bn", "SeqNum") 

val df3 = df2.select($"A", explode($"Bn"), $"SeqNum").toDF("A", "B", "C", "SeqNum")

val df4 = df3.withColumn("dummy", concat( $"SeqNum", lit("||"), $"A"))

val df5 = df4.select($"dummy", $"B", $"C").groupBy("dummy").pivot("B").agg(first($"C")) 

val df6 = df5.withColumn("A", substring_index(col("dummy"), "||", -1)).drop("dummy")
```

Now I trying to save the result to a csv file in HDFS

```
df6.withWatermark("event_time", "0 seconds")
  .writeStream
  .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("0 seconds"))
  .queryName("query_db")
  .format("parquet")
  .option("checkpointLocation", "/path/to/checkpoint")
  .option("path", "/path/to/output")
  //      .outputMode("complete")
  .start()
```

Now I get the below error.

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Append output mode not supported when there are streaming aggregations on streaming DataFrames/DataSets without watermark;;
>   EventTimeWatermark event_time#223: timestamp, interval

My doubt is that I am not performing any aggregation that will require it store the aggregated value beyond the processing time for that row. Why do I get this error? Can I keep watermarking as 0 seconds?

Any help on this will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding, watermarking is required only when you are performing window operation on event time. Spark used watermarking to handle late data and for the same purpose Spark needs to save older aggregation.

The following link explains this very well with example: 
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#handling-late-data-and-watermarking

I don't see any window operations in your transformation and if that is the case then I think you can try running the stream query without watermarking.

Comment: But I get the same error, if try to execute without the watermark

Comment: Have you got any solution ? am facing same issue.. am not able to write to HDFS location without watermark.. I have drop the watermark column while writing to hdfs.. its successful, but i want to group data without watermark..can you provide any approach

Answer (score 0):

when grouping spark streaming structures you have to already have the watermark in the dataframe and take it into account while grouping, by **including a window of the watermarks in your aggregation**.

```
    df.groupBy(col("dummy"), window(col("event_time"), "1 day")).
```